# Getting all rows between two timestamps

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulty getting this logic just right. I need to get all rows that match between two unix timestamps.

In this example, booking #1 already exists in the database. The times from booking #2 should have returned the data from booking #1 but it isn't working that way.

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong?

```
booking #1 start = 1385546460 = 11 / 27 / 13 @ 10:01:00am UTC
booking #1 stop  = 1385593140 = 11 / 27 / 13 @ 10:59:00pm UTC

booking #2 start = 1385560860 = 11 / 27 / 13 @ 2:01:00pm UTC
booking #2 stop  = 1385567940 = 11 / 27 / 13 @ 3:59:00pm UTC
```

---

```
SELECT
  t1.start
, t1.stop
, t1.booking_id
FROM booking AS t1
WHERE t1.location_id = 1 AND
(t1.start BETWEEN '1385560860' AND '1385567940' OR t1.stop  BETWEEN '1385560860' AND '1385567940')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booking 1 runs from approximately 10:00 – 22:00 and Booking 2 from 14:00 – 16:00, so of course neither end of Booking 1 will appear between the ends of Booking 2.

I think rather you are looking to compute the overlap of closed intervals:

```
WHERE t1.start <= t2.stop
      AND
      t1.stop  >= t2.start
```

That formulation will get overlapping ranges the way people usually think of them.  Given the diagram below, it will find that A, B, C, and D overlap with "Window," but E and F do not.

```
(time) ==========================>

Window:      |-------|
     A: |-----|
     B:        |--|
     C:   |------------|
     D:          |-------|
     E:  |-|
     F:                 |-----|
```

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight on this.